# Apple Appstore - Posting rating directly to apple appstore from app

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there any way to directly post rating to apple appstore without using any SKStoreReviewController API or showing apple store screen.

I wish to build custom UI to post customer's rating to appstore, that is reason i'm looking for alternate solution (even private API is also fine).

Any info on this appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apple has published a reference example for this here to give ratings within your app.

[Requesting App Store Reviews Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews)

It will only allow you to submit ratings not *reviews*. To submit reviews you have to redirect to the reviews url for your app on appstore.

```
URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXXX?action=write-review")
```